# How to install Wolfram Engine in Termux?

Tags: linux, free-wolfram-engine

How to install [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) for Linux in [Temux](https://termux.dev/)?
I did the following:

1. `pkg i xz-utils avahi inetutils`
2. `avahi-daemon`
3. `./WolframEngine_13.0.1_LINUX.sh`

Output:

```
Wolfram Engine 13.0.1 for LINUX Installer Archive                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                              
Verifying archive integrity.                                                                                                                                                                  
Extracting installer. ...........................                                                                                                                                             
touch: cannot touch '/tmp/InstallErrors-9580': No such file or directory                                                                                                                      
Unix/Installer/MathInstaller: line 1479: /tmp/InstallErrors-9580: No such file or directory                                                                                                   
Error: `unxz` not found. Please install "unxz" and re-run this installer.                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                              
Error: `unxz` not found. Please install "unxz" and re-run this installer.                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
cat: /tmp/InstallErrors-9580: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                       
Unix/Installer/MathInstaller: line 447: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

It seems that `unxz` command is not found, but there is the command, and `unxz --version` gives

```
xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.5
liblzma 5.2.5
```

There have been [other people asking the same question](https://www.zhihu.com/question/493148891),
but no one answered.

Comment: Try adding the command in your path or maybe doing the install via sudo (both wild guesses).

Comment: The command is already in PATH. There is no such thing as `sudo` in Termux.